# Broadcast not being received by directive $on

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to load a `ChartJS` charts directive when user's data is retrieved from `dashboard` controller.

The `broadcast` is received only when I refresh the page when I am on `dashboard`. If I click on the `dashboard` link and am routed to `dashboards` page, the broadcast is not sent.

Why does it broadcast when I refresh the dashboard page and not when I route to it?

Routing:

```
state('dashboard', {
    url : '/dashboard',
    templateUrl: '/html/pages/dashboard.html',
    controller: 'dashboardCtrl',
    resolve : {
        ProfileLoaded : function ($rootScope) {
            return $rootScope.loadProfile();
        }
    }
});
```

Dashboard.html:

```
<div class="dashboard">

    <!--Show Chart-->
    <chart></chart>

</div>
```

Charts Directive HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="charts chart_1">
        <canvas id="chart" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular
    .module('DDE')
    .controller('dashboardCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope',
        function($rootScope, $scope) {

            /*
                 Get User Dashboard
             */
            $scope.getDashboard = function() {

                Dashboard.getDashboard({
                    user_id : $rootScope.me.id
                }).success(function(res) {

                    populateChart(res);

                }).error(function(err){});
            };

            function populateChart (dashboard_data) {
                $rootScope.safeApply(function () {
                    $scope.$broadcast('dashboard-ready', dashboard_data);
                });
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Directive:

```
angular
    .module('DDE')
    .directive('chart',['$http', function ($http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: '/html/directives/charts.html',
            link: function(scope, elem, attr){

                scope.init = function(args) {
                    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                        drawChart(args);
                    });
                };

                //Not fired: Broadcast not received
                scope.$on('dashboard-ready', function(event, args) {
                    scope.init(args);
                });
            }
        }
}]);
```

---

Other: load profile promise for `stateProvider`:

```
    $rootScope.loadProfile = function () {
        return Me.getProfile({user_id : Cookies.get('user_id')}).success(function (res) {
            $rootScope.me = res;
        }).error(function (err) {
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        });
    };
```

---

EDIT: I've tried using a `$timeout` to delay the directive. This fixes the broadcast issues (meaning it's now received by directive), but gives me a new error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

```
        function populateChart (dashboard_data) {
            $rootScope.safeApply(function () {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('dashboard-ready', dashboard_data);
                }, 500);
            });
        }
```

Comment: use `$rootScope` instead of `$scope` since you want the event to be sent in several controllers. `$scope` inherits `$rootScope` and changing a controller reset `$scope`

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant Thanks for this. This doesn't work though- I've tried it

Comment: Based on your edits (eg. using the `$timeout` fixes the issue w/broadcast), it's just a timing error. When you navigate to the dashboard, the chart directive is not instantiated yet. Instead of trying to broadcast that the data is ready, just let the directive bind to the data. That seems like it would require a little refactoring to your directive, though.

Comment: @SunilD. can you explain what you mean `let the directive bind to the data`? Months later I'm getting this issue again in another portion of the app: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736744/directive-data-sometimes-does-not-appear-after-broadcast