# directive data sometimes does not appear after broadcast

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting this annoying bug with Angular where I broadcast data to a directive but the directive's `$on` doesn't receive it.

Therefore, my table doesn't populate at all and looks terrible to users.

test_results.html (contains an instance of the directive):

```
<div>
   <h1>Test Results</h1>
   ...
   <results></results>
</div>
```

resultsCtrl.js controller:

```
$timeout(function () {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('show-results', test_session.question_objects);
}, 100);
```

results.html directive template (most fields stripped out):

```
<div class="results">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td ng-if="average_times && !$root.is_mobile">
                    <span ng-click="sortType = 'question.average_timing'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                        Avg. Time
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="q in questions | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchQuestions track by $index">
                <td ng-if="q.average_timing && !$root.is_mobile" ng-click="$root.openDirections('question', q)">{{ q.average_timing }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
```

results.js directive:

```
scope.$on('show-results', function(event, test_session) {
    setTestSessionData(test_session);
});
...
function setTestSessionData (test_session) {
    scope.questions = test_session;
}
```

I cannot figure out when exactly this happens. At first I thought it's when I load the site for the first time, but I've tried that since and the data is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you do a `$rootScope.$broadcast` all the child scopes who have registered to those events via `$scope.$on` will catch the event. Same goes with directive scope also. If you update the model in the event listener , it will be updated in the view.

Working plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/4iokGsfPH5IqNdecjaGd?p=preview

Comment: So the only thing you're really doing differently here is binding the parent's results to the directive: `<results get-data="parent(results)"></results>` then `results: '&'`. I'm confused how this ensures that the data is being received in the `$on`. Shouldn't `$on` already be listening to broadcasts it has subscribed to?

Comment: Ignore the binding part ,  I simply added that , the only thing u have to observe , whenever u do a broadcast from parent controller , it is listened via  $on in directives local scope

Comment: Sasank, I still don't understand then. What's the difference in the scoping I've done and what you've done and why does your way always ensure content is loaded?

Comment: can you explain this please?

Comment: Share your code via a plunker , so that I can check it , just share the controller & directive code with some sample data, that would do.